# Accessing the values from Promise inside useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, express, promise

```
const useOnfidoFetch = (URL) => {


useEffect(() => {
  const appToken = axios.get('http://localhost:5000/post_stuff')
   .then((response) => response.data.data.data.json_data)
   .then((json_data) => {
      const id = json_data.applicant_id;
      const token = json_data.onfido_sdk_token;
      return {id, token};
   });
  if (appToken) {
    console.log('this is working!');
    OnfidoSDK.init({
      // the JWT token you generated above
      token: null,
      containerId: "root",
      steps: [
        {
          type: 'welcome',
          options: {
            title: 'Open your new bank account',
          },
        },
        'document'
      ],
      onComplete: function (data) {
        console.log('everything is complete');
        axios.post('https://third/party/api/v2/server-api/anonymous_invoke?aid=onfido_webapp', {
          params: {
            applicant_id: appToken.applicant_id
          }
       });
      }
    });
  }
}, [URL]);

}

export default function() {
  const URL = `${transmitAPI}/anonymous_invoke?aid=onfido_webapp`;
  const result = useOnfidoFetch(URL, {});

    return (
       <div id={onfidoContainerId} />
    );
}
```

I have refactored this dozens of times already, I am getting back some values from the `appToken` Promise, but I need to provide the `token` value from that Promise to that `token` property inside of `Onfido.init({})` and I need to provide the `id` to the `applicant_id` property and I continue to get `undefined`.

Comment: `appToken` will be undefined as the promise is not resolved yet by the time the `if (appToken)` runs. I would try to [resolve](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) the promise first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the token for something else as well, then i would suggest storing it in `useState`, and triggering `OnfidoSDK.init` when the value of that state changes.

Like this:

```
const useOnfidoFetch = (URL) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/post_stuff')
      .then((response) => response.data.data.data.json_data)
      .then((json_data) => {
          const token = json_data.onfido_sdk_token;
          setToken(token);
      })
  }, [URL])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!token) return;

    OnfidoSDK.init({
      // the JWT token you generated above
      token,
      containerId: "root",
      steps: [
        {
          type: 'welcome',
          options: {
            title: 'Open your new bank account',
          },
        },
        'document'
      ],
      onComplete: function (data) {
        console.log('everything is complete');
        axios.post('https://third/party/api/v2/server-api/anonymous_invoke?aid=onfido_webapp', {
          params: {
            applicant_id: appToken.applicant_id
          }
       });
      }
    });
  }, [token]);
}
```

Comment: I need both the `applicant_id` and the `onfido_sdk_token` as `appToken.applicant_id` would not work. I am trying your solution with `const id = json_data.onfido_sdk_token`. Except I get `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined;` so I am going to have to create another `useState` for `id`.

Comment: Yes, or if they always change together, you can use an object holding both properties for the state, so `const [auth, setAuth] = useState()`, then `setAuth({ applicant_id, token: onfido_sdk_token })`, and then `useEffect(() => { /* can reference auth.applicant_id and auth.token in here... */ }, [auth])`.

Answer (score 0):

Move the entire `if(appToken){ ... }` inside the body of the second .then((json_data) => { ... })

Something like this:

```
const useOnfidoFetch = (URL) => {


    useEffect(() => {
        const appToken = axios.get('http://localhost:5000/post_stuff')
            .then((response) => response.data.data.data.json_data)
            .then((json_data) => {
                const id = json_data.applicant_id;
                const token = json_data.onfido_sdk_token;
                
                // Here. This code will be executed after the values are available for id and token
                if (appToken) {
                    console.log('this is working!');
                    OnfidoSDK.init({
                        // the JWT token you generated above
                        token: null,
                        containerId: "root",
                        steps: [
                            {
                                type: 'welcome',
                                options: {
                                    title: 'Open your new bank account',
                                },
                            },
                            'document'
                        ],
                        onComplete: function (data) {
                            console.log('everything is complete');
                            axios.post('https://third/party/api/v2/server-api/anonymous_invoke?aid=onfido_webapp', {
                                params: {
                                    applicant_id: appToken.applicant_id
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                
                return {id, token};
            });
        
        // In here the promise is not yet finished executing, so `id` and `token` are not yet available
    }, [URL]);

};

export default function() {
    const URL = `${transmitAPI}/anonymous_invoke?aid=onfido_webapp`;
    const result = useOnfidoFetch(URL, {});

    return (
        <div id={onfidoContainerId} />
    );
}
```

For better readability, you could also move the `if(appToken){ ... }` block inside a separate function that takes `id, token` as arguments, which you can call from inside the `promise.then` block.